# Do electronic bug repellers work?

Tags: zoology, technology, electromagnetism, consumer-products

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ultrasound pest control devices](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5021/ultrasound-pest-control-devices)

Do electric insect repellers <sup>[example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0030T0RJC)</sup> work?

For context, I live in a rented house that has several of these installed. My personal observation is that they do *nothing* to repel bugs, but actually are effective at killing the bugs that enter the home — it just might take a day or two for the bug to die first. However, my personal observation may not be a typical result, hence the question: do these devices work? If it's a case of, "Yes... *but*", what do you need to look for to get an effective system?

Comment: Look at the 4th photo in the link you provided...

Comment: @nico - Unfortunately, it could easily have been photoshopped. Or special effects (aka dirt/paint).

Comment: Why is this a duplicate?  The other question was about ultrasonic pest control devices.  This one is an electromagnetic device (or magic rays, or something, considering that "creates a force field...by sending electronic pulses through the wiring").  Or does the text description ("other emissions") of the other question cover this?

Comment: @RexKerr Because that question [contains the answer to this one](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5021/ultrasound-pest-control-devices/5023#5023).